# Salesforce chatter Feed Item attachment download - Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I need to run a trigger when user download the attachment from Chatter feed item.

Use case: When user clicks on “Download” link on feed item attachment and downloads successfully, need to run a trigger that executes document locking (i.e., Document is locked for editing and no other user can download or upload new version until user unlocks it).

Is there any way to run trigger, when user clicks on “Download” link in feed item attachment, as show in below screen shot? Any inputs on this.

I tried googling it and gone through salesforce guide, but couldn’t find a way to do it.

[image]
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Generally triggers are written on DML operations such as insert, update, delete, undelete. I don't think Salesforce supports for Download option through trigger.

Comment: Thanks Devendra. Yes..triggers will run on DML operation such as insert,update,delete and undelete. Any other ideas/inputs how document locking can be achieved in chatter feed attachment.

Comment: At this moment, there is no standard functionality from salesforce for this one. However, you can vote for an idea for the same,  https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Lh1mAAC